# Custom fields for custom post types

Tags: theme-development

I have a custom post type for portfolio. To create one, you need to create a page with a particular template that i'm making, named page-portfolio.

Now, a portfolio post has custom fields as well. But, how can i make a custom field that is displayed in the post only if i select the 'portfolio' template ? That is, a custom field tied to the usage of the portfolio template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confusing you're mixing up the terminology of WordPress. A custom post type acts like a *post* and not a *page*. If you have a custom post type called "portfolio" and use the proper template hierarchy, you don't have to do anything special. But you will need to name it `single-portfolio.php` and not  `page-portfolio.php`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

If on the other hand, if you simply want to use "page" templates ( I think that is what you mean) you will need to write a conditional to display the post meta for only the `page-portfolio.php`.

The logic is along the lines of:

```
if (is_page_template('page-portfolio.php')) 
the_meta();
```

Your default page most likely already has `the_meta();` though so you will most likely want to use `get_post_meta` or `get_post_custom` so you can have fields specific to your "portfolio".

ps. It's much easier to just use a custom post type (not a page template) for this sort of thing .

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Function_Reference
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template

Comment: I probably did not make myself clear. There is a custom post type AND a custom page template in my case. The type is a portfolio item, the page is a showcase of the items. The conditional display is probably what i need though, yes. I'm trying it thanx :)

Comment: ah was confusing since they seem to have the same name, the `is_page_template` is probably what you want.

Comment: hmm, thinking about it, this actually checks about the template, when displaying that template. I actually want to dynamically create an admin meta box when the portfolio template is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently figuring out a similar problem, I think.

Using the Custom Field Template plugin, you can add different types of fields, including TinyMCE and checkboxes.

This article should help:
http://www.designfaire.com/blog/custom-post-types-and-custom-field-template-in-wordpress-3-0-beta-2/